# Android voice call in android 5.1

Tags: android

I have a android voice call apk which is used to make,receive,end and reject call ,it works fine in android version lower than 5.0 ,**receive call** is not working for **version 5.0** and above.  Make,end and reject call is working fine.

This is my code below please check It,I think this would help..

```
 private BroadcastReceiver receiveCallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Recieved receive call intent");

        String requestId = intent.getStringExtra("REQUEST_ID");
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Request id is:"+requestId);

        try {
             Thread.sleep(2000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            //we don't want
        }

        if (telephonyManager.getCallState() == telephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Phone is ringing");
            Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
            buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Received the call");
            sendResult(requestId, "PASS",0,null,null);
        }
        else{
             Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Phone is not ringing to accept call");
             sendResult(requestId,"FAIL",ErrorCodes.PHONE_RING_ERROR,"Phone is not ringing to accept call",null);

        }
    }
};
```